# Resolve data (from backend) into Root Component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have been struggling with this issue for quite some time now:

I am trying to resolve data from the backend (re-validate user token from local storage) into the root component so I can set the HTTP headers accordingly.

The resolve into "normal" components works just fine, I'm only struggling with the root component.

main.ts

```ts
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

app.routes.ts

```ts
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    resolve: {
        token: LoginService
    },
    children: [
        ...HomeRoutes,
        ...LoginRoutes,
        ...DashboardRoutes
    ]
}];
```

app.module.ts

```ts
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes),
        MaterialModule.forRoot(),
        FlexLayoutModule.forRoot(),
        LoginModule,
        HomeModule,
        DashboardModule
    ],
    providers: [
        SessionService,
        LocalstorageService,
        HttpClient,
        LoginService
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
```

app.component.ts

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'nos-app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) {
        // this is undefined
        console.log(this._route.snapshot.data['token']);
    }
}
```

dashboard.component.ts

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'nos-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) {
        // this is fine
        console.log(this._route.snapshot.data['token']);
    }
}
```

Thanks alot for any advice!!!

Regards
Robin

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score -3):

```ts
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this._route.data.subscribe(data => {
          console.log(data['token']);
        })
    }
}
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard

Comment: This will log `undefined` because there is no route for `AppComponent`.